# Advantages and drawbacks to implementing core methods of a scripting language in the underlying language

Tags: language-design, scripting-language, language-implementation

**Background**: I am writing a scripting language interpreter as a way to test out some experimental language ideas.  I am to the point of writing the core set of standard methods (functions) for built-in types. Some of these methods need to directly interface with the underlying data structures and must be be written using the underlying language (Haskell in my case, but that is not important for this question).  Others can be written in the scripting language itself if I choose.

**Question**: What are the advantages and drawbacks to implementing core library functions in either the underlying language or in the language itself?

**Example**: My language includes as a built-in type `Array`s that work just like you think they do -- ordered data grouped together.  An `Array` instance (this is an OO language) has methods `inject`, `map` and `each`. I have implemented `inject` in Haskell.  I could write `map` and `each` in Haskell as well, or I could write them in my language using `inject`.  For example:

```
def map(fn)
    inject([]) do |acc,val|
        acc << fn(val)
    #end inject
#end def map 

def each(fn)
    inject(nil) do |acc,val|
        fn val
    #end inject
#end def each
```

I would like to know what the advantages and drawbacks are to each choice?

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage is that you're eating your own dog food. You get to write more code in your language, and hence get a better idea of what it's like, at least for generic library code. This is not only a good opportunity to notice deficiencies in the language design, but also in the implementation. In particular, you'll find more bugs and you'll find out whether abstractions like these can be implemented efficiently or whether there is a fundamental barrier that forces one to write performance-sensitive code in another language.

This leads, of course, to one disadvantage: It may be slower, either in programmer time or run time performance. However, the first is valuable experience for you, the language designer, and the second should be incentive to optimize the implementation (assuming you care about performance) rather than working around the problem — it weakens your language and doesn't solve the same problem for other users who can't modify the implementation.

There are also advantages for future-proofing the implementation. The language should remain stable in the face of major modifications under the hood, so you'll have to rewrite less code when doing those. Conversely, the functions will be more like other user-defined functions: There is a real risk that, when defining some standard library function or type in the implementation language, subtle differences sneak in that make the type or function behave in a way that can't be emulated by the language.